# Return action to action in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Why my return to InsertUpdate() from Insert action not working when calling insert action using jQuery load function.It shows following error:

> The partial view 'Insert' was not found or no view engine supports the 
>       searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>
> ~/Views/AppClient/Insert.aspx
>   ~/Views/AppClient/Insert.ascx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Insert.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Insert.ascx
>   ~/Views/AppClient/Insert.cshtml
>   ~/Views/AppClient/Insert.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Insert.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Insert.vbhtml

```
public ActionResult Insert()
{
   return InsertUpdate();
}
private ActionResult InsertUpdate()
{
   return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: what mean by not working? what is the error? how do u return, there r lots of question that u yet to explain clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the actual action invoked is `InsertUpdate()` the context in which it is invoked is still the `Insert()` method (mainly because `action` in your routing values would still be `insert`).

Hence, when you don't specify a view to be rendered in your call to `PartialView()`, the name of the view is based on the current routing data.

Try this instead:

```
return PartialView("InsertUpdate");
```

Or manually change the routing data upon invoking `InsertUpdate()`:

```
public ActionResult Insert()
{
    this.RouteData.Values["action"] = "InsertUpdate";

    return InsertUpdate();
}
```